# No puedo usar caracteres especiales en Next.js: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8"

Tags: reactjs, utf-8, next.js

Soy nuevo con Next.js y me he descargado [este template](https://mui.com/store/items/devias-kit/) para trastear con el código.

Estoy intentando modificar el texto que se muestra en la opción "Dashboard" de la barra lateral, de tal manera que quiero mostrar el texto "Menú Principal" en vez de "Dashboard".

```
// He modificado lo siguiente en `src/components/dashboard-sidebar.js`:
...

const items = [
  {
    href: '/',
    icon: (<ChartBarIcon fontSize="small" />),
    title: 'Dashboard'
  },

...

// Ahora esta asi, solo he modificado el title
... 

const items = [
  {
    href: '/',
    icon: (<ChartBarIcon fontSize="small" />),
    title: 'Menú Principal'
  },

...
```

Pero cuando voy a probarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

```
error - ./src/components/dashboard-sidebar.js
Error: Failed to read source code from <path hasta el fichero dashboard-sidebar.js>

Caused by:
    stream did not contain valid UTF-8
```

Supongo que sí es posible usar caracteres especiales pero, ¿cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: Usando un editor que soporte UTF-8 y asegurándote que el archivo es de esa codificación o convertirlo a ella antes del cambio, pues tu texto lleva acentos y no deberías editarlo en otra página de códigos que no sea UTF-8.

Comment: Gracias. Estaba usando el formato Windows-1252 y al parecer no usa el mismo código que UTF-8 para las vocales con acentos. Cambiando eso ya no aparece el error.

Comment: Vale, perfecto, acabo de agregar una respuesta para no dejar a la pregunta pendiente eternamente. Sírvete aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te decía en los comentarios, que me acabas de confirmar:

> Usando un editor que soporte UTF-8 y asegurándote que el archivo es de
> esa codificación o convertirlo a ella antes del cambio, pues tu texto
> lleva acentos y no deberías editarlo en otra página de códigos que no
> sea UTF-8.

Lo pongo como respuesta para que la pregunta no quede pendiente de ella eternamente.